# Spring validation with annotaion @valid

Tags: spring, validation, annotations

I'm trying to understand @Valid annotation provided Spring.

1. If @Valid is being used, then in the code there is initbinder and required validater. I understood this.
2. Incase of String or Date, can we place @Valid before these requestParams/ PathVariables so that they can get validated for null validates automatically without any customized validator.

Thanks in advance.